# How to remove all tables of accumulo or format hadoop files for accumulo

Tags: hadoop, accumulo

I want to clear all records in accumulo for my local machine and want to delete unused tables created while testing. I found delete table command which can be used from accumulo shell, however that will require much of manual works for deleting large number of tables. I also tried [instructions](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/format_and_start_hdfs.html) to format namenode of hadoop but that doesn't seems to work.

How can I remove all tables and have fresh start with accumulo datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I deleted all the tables using command `deletetable -f -p Test.*`. Which will delete all tables with prefix "Test". In short we can write a script to delete all tables.

To remove all the hadoop files from accumulo, follow the steps:

1. Stop accumulo
2. Run`$ hdfs dfs -rm -R -skipTrash hdfs://localhost:9000/accumulo`.
   Where `hdfs://localhost:9000/accumulo` is path to accumulo data.
3. Re-run `$ accumulo init`.
4. Start Accumulo `$ ./bin/start-all.sh`.